# What is the best way to work with date/time period in Doctrine2 or PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine

Does PHP have standard types for working with date/time period?

For example, now I have entity Period:

```
class Period
{ 
    /** 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $start; 

    /** 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $end;
}
```

And I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I need comparison functions and so on. Can you suggest me something? Thanks.

P.S. I know about [\DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), but I talk about period with specified dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at PHP's [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/DatePeriod) class. I'm sure it is exactly what you're looking for.

There are some good examples of its use on that page too.

It is worth noting that, as DatePeriod implements the Traversable interface you can use it in a foreach loop where each item will be a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/DateTime) object.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very inattentive.